# Which to use, addSnapshotListener() or getDocuments()

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a little bit confused about addSnapshotListener and getDocuments. As I read in the firebase docs, getDocuments() is retrieving data once and addSnapshotListener is retrieving in real-time.

What I want to ask.

If I'm using getDocuments, and im changing some documents in the Firestore , it will not make the change in the app ? But if im using addSnapshotListener it will ?

I'm making an delivery app, which is the best to use to store pictures of food , descriptions etc.

This is what im using to retrieve labels and pictures from my app :

```
db.collection("labels").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            } else {
                for document in snapshot!.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                    let newEntry = Labels(
                        firstLabel: data["firstLabel"] as! String,
                        secondLabel: data["secondLabel"] as! String,
                        photoKey: data["photoKey"] as! String
                    )
                    
                        
                        
                        
                    self.labels
                        .append(newEntry)
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableViewTest.reloadData()
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getDocuments` will return results one time, with the current Firestore data.

`addSnapshotListener` will return an initial result set (same as `getDocuments`) *and* get called any time that data changes.

If your data is modified in Firestore and you've used `getDocuments`, your app will not be notified of those changes. For example, in your delivery app, perhaps the item goes out-of-stock while the user is using it. Or, the price gets changed, the user is logged in from another device, etc -- many possibilities for why the data might change. By using a snapshot listener, you'd get notified if any of these changes happen.

However, if you're relatively confident you don't need updates to the data (like getting a user's address from the database, for example), you could opt to just use `getDocuments`.

Comment: Thank you for your time. So if im publishing an app (using getDocuments0), it will  publish with the actual database, and if I will modify something in my Firestore, the app will remain the same, without any change ? :)

Comment: `getDocuments()` will return the current state of Firestore at the time when the function is called -- not when you publish your app.

Comment: I have this method implemented in my viewdidload, so every time the app is loaded, it will get my database with whatever data is in it ?

Comment: Is there a difference in memory/performance?  If not might as well use addSnapshotListener all the time right?

Comment: If you're getting one collection *one time* and don't care about updates, one would almost certainly choose `getDocuments`. If one wanted updates, `addSnapshotListener` would be the way to go, as far as I can tell.